# Docusign Android SDK Security questions does does not show up on Production

Tags: android, docusignapi

Docusign Android SDK Security questions does does not show up on Production.
I've already active the security questions on Docusign Web and it is working on iOS native app, but not on Android app.

Comment: are you using the developer/demo/sandbox account? that is not the same as production

Comment: No, we already are using the Docusign live account instead of sanbox.

Answer (score 0):

Alexandra, When you say its working on iOS native app, can you let me know if it is your iOS application integrated with DocuSign native iOS SDK. And confirm if it is not working in your android application integrated with Docusign Android SDK.

Comment: yes, we are using DocuSign native iOS SDK with online mode, and Docusign Android SDK with offline mode. Also we tested it with Docusign live account.

Comment: Alexandra, can you confirm that you try to set "In Person ID Check Question" in DocuSign web portal, then In-person signer should get this question before begin signing in android app. And that question is not coming. Can you confirm if that is the issue?

Comment: If that is the issue, feel free to file an issue in https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/issues and we will take a look at it.

Comment: I'm doble checking all the DocuSign web portal configuration

Comment: I set "In Person ID Check Question" in DocuSign web portal and In-person signer does not get the question before signing in android app. So I created an issue on gitbub. https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

are you planning to use the security questions feature in your implementation in the mobile app?